# Add 'PageSetupAccessory' to PrintPanel for PDFDocument

Tags: swift, pdfview, nsprintoperation, nsprintinfo, nsprintpanel

I have an app which displays a `PDFView`, and I want it to print the PDF file from the view. Also, I want the Print panel to show the Page Setup Accessory (i.e. the Paper Size, Orientation and Scale settings, like in Preview, which appear as one panel of the drop-down list of options).

Currently, I'm mistakenly printing the `PDFView`, not the PDF document itself. This only gives me one page and includes the scrollbars in the print-out!  I can't see how to `init` an `NSPrintOperation` referencing a `PDFDocument` rather than the `PDFView`.

Here's my code, which works, but isn't what I want. I presume I'll have to override either the `printDocument` or `printOperation` functions of `NSDocument` with similar code that defines the Panel and the Info.

```
func thePrintInfo() -> NSPrintInfo {
    let thePrintInfo = NSPrintInfo()
    thePrintInfo.horizontalPagination = .automatic // Tried fit
    thePrintInfo.verticalPagination = .automatic // Tried fit
    thePrintInfo.isHorizontallyCentered = true // Tried false
    thePrintInfo.isVerticallyCentered = true // Tried false
    thePrintInfo.leftMargin = 0.0
    thePrintInfo.rightMargin = 0.0
    thePrintInfo.topMargin = 0.0
    thePrintInfo.bottomMargin = 0.0
    thePrintInfo.jobDisposition = .spool
    return thePrintInfo
}

// Need to show the 'Page Setup' Options as an Accessory
// e.g. Paper size, orientation.
@IBAction func printContent(_ sender: Any) {
    let printOperation = NSPrintOperation(view: thePDFView, printInfo: thePrintInfo())
    let printPanel = NSPrintPanel()
    printPanel.options = [
        NSPrintPanel.Options.showsCopies,
        NSPrintPanel.Options.showsPrintSelection,
        NSPrintPanel.Options.showsPageSetupAccessory,
        NSPrintPanel.Options.showsPreview
    ]
    printOperation.printPanel = printPanel
    printOperation.run()
}
```

Comment: What should be printed, the view or the pdf-document? See [printOperation(for:scalingMode:autoRotate:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfdocument/1436075-printoperation)

Comment: @Willeke That's the problem! I'm currently printing the view, but I want to print the document. There doesn't seem to be a way of initializing an NSPrintOperation without referencing a view.

Comment: How about the linked `printOperation(for:scalingMode:autoRotate:)` of `PDFDocument`?

Comment: Can you give me a clue how I use it in the context of the app, and how I get the PrintPanel settings in there?

Comment: I think it's something like `let printOperation = thePDFDocument.printOperation(for:thePrintInfo(), scalingMode:.pageScaleDownToFit, autoRotate:true)` instead of `let printOperation = NSPrintOperation(view: thePDFView, printInfo: thePrintInfo())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Willeke's comments, I've come up with the following, which seems to work well. (Minor quibble is that the Print dialog isn't a sheet.) If anyone has any improvements, please post a better answer.

```
@IBAction func printContent(_ sender: Any) {
   let printOperation = thePDFView.document?.printOperation(for: thePrintInfo(), scalingMode: .pageScaleNone, autoRotate: true)
printOperation?.printPanel = thePrintPanel()
printOperation?.run()
}
```

Comment: [runModal(for:delegate:didRun:contextInfo:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsprintoperation/1532065-runmodal) displays a sheet.

Comment: @Willeke Yes, I saw that, but got scared by delegates and selectors and pointers. I'll have a go.

Comment: The delegate, selector and context are optional: `printOperation.runModal(for: window, delegate: nil, didRun: nil, contextInfo: nil)`

Comment: @Willeke Hmm. Not quite sure what my Window is. I don't think I've defined one. Anyway, it's working fine just with run().

Comment: `window` is the parent window of the sheet.

Comment: That's another question, I think. Thanks for your help.